# Why does the content of the function load, but not the function when it is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, call

I'm having an issue with a function I'm calling (using jQuery).
My issue is that when I attempt call a function within another function, that first one is not being called. However, when I place the contents of the failed function into the one calling said failed function, the code executes fine. I'll show you what I'm talking about:

```
$('form.register .submit').click(validateRegister);

function submitStart() {

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().addClass('processing');

    var $processing = $('#processing');
    $processing.show();

    var $endNote = $this.parent().find('#endNote')
    $endNote.slideDown();

}

function validateRegister(){

    submitStart();

}
```

See, when the contents of submitStart() are places into the validateRegister(), they code executes. However, when calling the function as it shows in this code, it fails to work. I've considered scope (at least to my knowledge) to no avail.

Any help is extremely appreciated, thank you!

Comment: have you tried `$('form.register .submit').click(submitStart);`

Comment: It's weird, I tried the exact code you have here with a form I made and it works and executes the submitStart()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're losing your expected `this` value, so the `submitStart` is likely getting called, but doesn't work properly.

Do this:

```
function validateRegister(){

    submitStart.call( this );

}
```

Here you're calling the `submitStart` method via the `.call()` method, which is available on function instances.

The `.call()` method lets you manually set the value of `this` in the function you're calling.

So because you've assigned `validateRegister` as the handler, jQuery makes sure the value of `this` is your element. But since `validateRegister` is calling another function, it carries the responsibility of making sure that function has the proper `this` value.

---

Just keep in mind that when you call any function like this:

```
someFunction();
```

...the value of `this` in that function will be `window`, unless you manually set it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

`var $this = $(this);` is returning the window.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `this`. When you use `validateRegister` as an event hander, jQuery automatically makes sure that `this` refers to the DOM element that dispatched the event. But when you call your separate function, the scope isn't being set correctly, so `this` probably refers to the `window` object (that's the default when you refer to `this` in the global scope). To fix it, the easiest way would be to pass the element along as an argument:

```
function submitStart(element) {

    var $this = $(element);
    $this.parent().addClass('processing');

    var $processing = $('#processing');
    $processing.show();

    var $endNote = $this.parent().find('#endNote')
    $endNote.slideDown();

}

function validateRegister(){
    // "this" is the DOM element
    submitStart(this);
}
```

As @Andrew noted, you can also set the value of `this` in `submitStart` by using [the `.apply()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) of the `submitStart` function.

Answer (score 0):

`this` will no longer be referencing the clicked element but will represent `window` instead.  You can change `submitStart` so that it accepts a parameter and pass `this` to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have an issue with `this` not being what you think it is.

Try this:

`submitStart.call(this)`